# Parsing textfile to access database in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am trying to store the information from text file into the database. This is what I have but could not figure out what to do next.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim filename As String
    filename = Application.StartupPath + "\darsReport.txt"
    Dim iofile As New StreamReader(filename)
    If File.Exists(filename) Then
        Dim ioline As String
        Dim ID, studentName, currentGPA, ReqGPA, expectedGraduation

        ioline = iofile.ReadLine

        While Not ioline = ""
            Dim mysplit = Split(ioline, "   ")
            ID = mysplit(1)
            studentName = mysplit(0)
            expectedGraduation = mysplit(2)
            currentGPA = mysplit(3)
            ReqGPA = mysplit(4)

        End While

    Else
        MsgBox(filename + "Does not exist.")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

After this you need to run an `INSERT` query on your database table. The simplest way to do that is to use `SqlCommand` class (assuming that you have a SQL Server database):

```
Dim con as new SqlConnection("Your Connection String Here")
con.Open()
Dim cmd as New SqlCommand("", con)
cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO [YourTable](ID, Name, CurrentGPA) VALUES({0}, '{1}', {2})", ID, studentName, currentGPA)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Use this code block inside your loop and all your rows will be inserted into the database. However note that this is really the very basic way of doing it and a lot more code should be written to properly handle exceptions, invalid data etc. Also this method can easily be exploited using SQL Injections. Far better apporaches exist in .NET (e.g. DataSets and Entity Framework) that should rather be used for this task.

Comment: I am using MS Access 2013.

Comment: @agirlinstates: No problem. You can use `OledbConnection` instead of `SqlConnnection` and `OledbCommand` instead of `SqlCommand` in the above code. Rest of it should work as it is.